# represent an image in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, image-processing

Can we represent a grayscale image as a matrix of values, and then apply all our linear algebra techniques to that? Like finding the column space and null space, reason about the matrix structure.
Actually I am a bit confused. Normally (in algebra) images are represented as two-variable functions of intensities. But in linear algebra, can that two dimensional thing explode to a multi-dimensional representation of vectors?

Comment: Certainly you can represent a grayscale image as a matrix of values. Color images usually associate three or four numbers with each point. I'm not sure that linear algebra can support a "matrix of vectors", but certainly you can form three or four matrices, one for each color component. Image processing will often be performed on blocks (submatrices) of these larger matrices. I don't know much about image processing, but I would imagine that linear algebraic notions such as eigenvalues or SVD for each block would be very useful, and a google search confirms that :-)

Comment: Exactly the point. Can we consider the block as data values for a random vector. (vector of random variables)?

Comment: Certainly we can. I believe the entire discipline of statistical image processing treats the image data as an instance of a stochastic process.

Comment: See also: eigenfaces, for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface